# In Linq to SQL is it better return multiple results sets at once or call the DB using multiple stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures, high-load

I am creating a very data intensive, high volume web site.  Every aspect of the website is driven by interactions with the MSSQL DB that I am using.  On one page there are 10-12 different resultsets that I need to utilize in my page.  So I need to know the best practice when it comes to using Linq-to-SQL and multiple results sets with a web application.

Should I have it return multiple result sets, create classes that will then receive the data and utilize it that way or just call 10-12 Store Procedures and return the data to the previous generated LINQ To SQL Data Classes?

Thanks for your help everyone!  I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as always the fewer trips to the database the better, but it all depends on whether or not that approach is maintainable and fits the architecture of your application. I personally have not worked on an application where the number of trips to the database was so important that I had to fetch everything up front, but each situation is different.

Comment: If are getting millions of hits per day to that page then you are getting 10-12 million hits to the DB on that page alone.  How would I even determine or analyze if I would be better to wrap it in one send/receive message and then parse it out in the app code?

Comment: Well since the ADO.NET providers are going to use connection pooling regardless of what you do, it really becomes simply a matter of network overhead. If the network connection between the web server and database is fast, it probably doesn't matter much. If it's remotely located, it could matter a lot. But the DB is going to do the same amount of work processing one command or a batch of commands.